# How do I uninstall MongoDB on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, uninstall, mongodb

My installation is not from MacPorts or Homebrew. I did it from the 10gen build as specified in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/